# Python KivyMD взять информацию из MDTextField

Tags: python, kivy

Как взять , написанную пользователем информацию, из MDTextField ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.mdtextfield.text
Но это обязательно должно быть в классе,в котором вы создали разметку
И в файле kv 
Пропишите- mdtextfield: mdtextfield.
И в самом Mdtextfield -
id: mdtextfield